In vuetify combobox how to transform into uppercase each character typed by the user
Can someone know in vuetify combobox on how to transform each character or letter into uppercase that being typed by user. Thanks
I tried these events change, input and update:search-input to get the combobox model value and transform into uppercase but it didn't work.

vuetify2 or vuetify3?

I think the only way to get to the search value is through a template ref. Then you can update it on update:search:
<template>
  <v-combobox
    ref="comboboxref"
    @update:search="turnSearchToUppercase"
  />
</template>
<script setup>
  const comboboxref = ref()
  const turnSearchToUppercase = () => {
    const search = comboboxref.value.search
    if (search) {
      comboboxref.value.search = search.toUpperCase()
    }
  }
</script>



const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  template: `
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-combobox
            v-model="value"
            :items="items"
            ref="combo"
            @update:search="turnSearchToUppercase"
          />
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
  `,
  data: () => ({
      items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
      value: 'foo',
  }),
  methods: {
    turnSearchToUppercase() {
      const search = this.$refs.combo?.search
      if (!search) {
        return
      }
      this.$refs.combo.search = search.toUpperCase()
    },
  },

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>




If you only want to change the display behavior.
Besides @moritz's answer, there is another workaround is using CSS:
.your-combobox-selector input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

e.g
<template>
  <v-combobox
    class="your-combobox-selector"
  />
</template>

global CSS:
.your-combobox-selector input{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

